# Sets that have the property of Baire

Tags: general-topology

Can I say that a set $A$ has the [property of Baire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire), if and only if it is of the form $A=(B \setminus C) \cup D$ where $B$ is regular open and $C,D$ are of first Category?

Are there any other useful descriptions of sets that admits the property of Baire?

Thank you!

Comment: This might be of use: [*Notes on the Baire Property* by Gabriel Conant](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~gconant/Math/Baire%20Property.pdf). Also, try this google search: ["baire property" AND "regular open"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22baire+property%22+%22regular+open%22).